# Is unused memory in address space protected

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Is the unused memory in address space of a process protected by just having read permission, so that writing to a location pointed by an unitialized pointer for example always cause a page fault to be trapped by the OS? Or is it not the case, and every memory location besides the code (which ofcourse is given read only access), is given write access?

I'm asking this because my friend was showing me his code where he didn't initialize a pointer and wrote in the memory pointed by it, but still his program wasn't crashing with mingw gcc compiler for windows but always crashing with visual c++, in mac or linux.

What I think is that the OS do not protect memory for unused areas and the crashing was being caused because in the code generated by the mingw, the random pointer value was pointing to some used area such as stack, heap or code, while in other cases it was pointing to some free area. But if the OS really doesn't protect the unused areas, wouldn't these sort of bugs, such as uninitialized pointers be difficult to debug?

I guess this is why it is advised to always assign NULL to a pointer after calling `delete` or `free`, so that when something is accessed with it, it really causes a visible crash.

Comment: Yes, uninitialized pointer errors are difficult to debug.  The symptoms are often very mysterious.   If you ever find yourself saying "the code couldn't possibly do that....", suspect uninitialized pointers.

Comment: The observed difference between compilers may relate to what an uninitialized pointer is initialized to. A "safe" approach from the compiler's perspective is to initialize all pointers to NULL - that way, if you use it, you will cause a segfault rather than point to a random location in memory... But this is implementation specific and may explain what you observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the OS. In some configurations, for example, [ExecShield](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/execshield/) will protect most of the memory that goes out of the bounds of the program, and also it is common that the first few bytes of the data segment to be protected (to signal access with NULL pointers), but it may be the case that the pointer actually points to a valid, arbitrary, memory address within the program.

Answer (score 3):

Uninitialized pointers don't necessarily to point to unused address space. They could very well be values that happen to point to writeable memory. Such as a pointer on the stack that happened to be where a previously executed function stored a valid address.

Comment: I'm asking the case where they are pointing to some free area. I know it will crash for sure when it points to used areas, such as stack or code memory.

Comment: It might not crash at all if it points to the stack, the stack is usually read/write. code segments are usually read/exec and on some architectures might be exec only

Comment: It will also almost surely not crash (immediately) if it points to *freed* memory, since most implementations don't unmap or return to the OS most freed memory.

Comment: The point is that if the pointer is uninitialized it can be pointing at anything - code, stack, freed memory, memory allocated elsewhere in the code, unaligned memory, NULL, OS memory, memory hardware mapped to a physical device (subject to the constraints of the OS), whatever.

Answer (score 3):

In a typical, current server/desktop OS (and quite a few smaller systems such as cell phones as well) you have virtual memory. This means the OS builds a table that translates from the virtual address your code uses, to a physical address that specifies the actual memory being addressed. This mapping is normally done in "pages" -- e.g., a 4KB chunk of memory at a time.

At least in the usual case, parts of the address space that aren't in use at all simply won't be mapped at all -- i.e., the OS won't build an entry in the table for that part of the address space. Note, however, that memory that is allocated will (of necessity) be rounded to a multiple of the page size, so each chunk of memory that's in use will often be followed by some small amount that's not really in use, but still allocated and "usable". Since protection is also (normally) done on a per-page basis, if the rest of that page is (say) Read-only, the remainder at the tail end will be the same.

Comment: Jerry, I know about virtual memory and pages et all, I was just asking if the free areas were protected by just giving read access.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Most pages that aren't in use are set up with no page descriptor, so they're not read-only or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Memory protection is not provided by c/c++.  You may find that the pointer just happens to contain a pointer to valid memory, e.g. a previous function has a ptr variable on the stack and another function called later just happens to use the same stack space for a pointer.

The following code will print "Hello" if compiled and ran with gcc:
    #include

```
char buffer[10];

void function1(void) {
    char * ptr = buffer;
    sprintf(buffer, "Hello");
    return;
}

void function2(void) {
    char * ptr2;
    printf("%s\n", ptr2);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

For debug builds some compilers (I know that Visual Studio used to do this) will secretly initialise all variables like ptr2 to a bad value to detect these kinds of error.

With C normally you find out that memory has been abused by the OS killing your program.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, I assume the answer is "No, unused memory in address is not space protected."  C isn't sophisticated enough to handle such instances.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C, but with process memory map protection, that depends on the OS.

Comment: But such protection can be built into languages, and I assume when he mentioned "space protection," he was harping on that particular languages' attribute (whether it's built in or not): exceptions.